# Is there any difference of relation and morphism?

Tags: category-theory

Well, my thoughts for now is that [relation](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(mathematics)) is a mapping idea defined on $Set$ category (the Set Theory Context). Relations, for instance, they are a more broad idea than functions, because a function is a relation which need always obey the properties of `total` and `functional`.

By another hand, on Category Theory world, [morphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism) is even a more abstract ideia for mapping, which is used not only inside of the Set  Theory.

However, seems to me that a `relation` is kind of morphism. But the inverse is not true, right? Or is?

$ relation \Rightarrow morphism $ but $ morphism \not \Rightarrow relation $

What rules a `relation` need to obey, but morphism don't? What makes they different?

Comment: Not always, endomorphism implies the reflexive relation.

Comment: Can you elaborate it? What are you referring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some categories, the morphisms are relations. In particular, there is a category, often referred to as $\mathbf{Rel}$, whose morphisms consist of arbitrary binary relations between sets with relational composition. Conversely, a morphism in some arbitrary category need not even be a set, let alone a relation.

An analogy (that's more than analogy) would be to group theory. A group is a set of elements and a binary operation on that set satisfying some laws. The notion of group does not require the elements to be any particular thing. You can have a group of numbers, or a group of permutation, or a group of points in a manifold.

The situation is the same for categories. A category is a family of hom-sets and a family of binary operations on those hom-sets that satisfy some laws. The elements of those hom-sets, i.e. morphisms, can be anything. You can have a category where the morphisms are numbers, or permutations, or points in a manifold, or, also, functions or relations.

Comment: Can you give an example where a morphism is a number?

Comment: @Make42 The category with one object and $\Bbb Z$-many arrows from that object to itself, one for each integer, and the composition law is $n+m=(n+m)$ for composing the $n$th arrow with the $m$th arrow

Comment: @FShrike: This might go into the philosophy of mathematics than mathematics itself, but I do not see how this would make the arrows to _be_ numbers. I would rather say that the arrows are somewhat associated with the numbers and then based on the association we are deriving rules for composition.

Comment: @Make42 You could choose the arrow sets to be your favourite set encoding of the numbers $1,2,3,\cdots$, you could say $C(\ast,\ast)=\Bbb Z$ as a definition. Now the arrows “literally are” integers

Comment: However there’s the subtlety that we don’t really mean one particular set when we say $\Bbb Z$, we just mean any model of it. Well, this is clearer for $\Bbb R$, where there are Dedekind or Cauchy reals as models, and you need to do work to show they are equivalent, and there are a gazillion other models, … not worth thinking about though

Comment: @FShrike: I am not sure I understand. 1. I am aware of [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding), but not "set encoding". What is that? 2. Do you mean that you encode each arrow with a number or each number with an arrow? 3. In either case, how would that make an arrow literally to be a number? 4. By "any model of it" you mean a logical structure from model theory, right? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_(mathematical_logic) 5. For $\mathbb R$ you refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Explicit_constructions_of_models, right?

Comment: @Make42 I just mean, no one really cares what is actually encoding the number $2$. A classic way is to write it as $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}$, I think. Hopefully I didn't drop any brackets. But I could just as well represent it as $\{\emptyset\}$. Not relevant. So your $\Bbb Z$ could on a literal set-equality sense be different to my $\Bbb Z$, but no one cares about that because our integers both do the same thing

Comment: @Make42 It depends how you decide to encode categories in general. But $C(\ast,\ast):=\Bbb Z$ is a valid declaration of an arrow set, or at least it should be. So the arrows literally would be elements of $\Bbb Z$. I don't really mean about model theory, because I personally don't know any model theory at all. I just mean a set that does what we want. E.g. see the "Synthetic definition of the reals". I am not qualified to say anything more about this, I don't study set theory. I just wanted to say, I don't believe "how can the arrows *be* numbers?" can have a clear answer, things are murky