# How is the idea of morphisms between objects in category theory different from the idea of relations between sets in set theory?

Tags: functions, category-theory, set-theory, relations

If possible, please also give examples where the latter is not the former and vice-versa:)

I'm having much trouble distinguishing these ideas. In set theory, you can have  multiple sets $A$, $B$ and $C$....which are collections of elements, and you can have relations among them $R_{AB}, R_{BC}, R_{AC}.... $

Let's name the set of above sets a **"category set"**. Now one may take multiple category sets and define relations among them. Let's name the set of these sets a "Functor".

**I want to know**, how are these ideas different from the corresponding ideas in category theory?

Comment: Relations in set theory are an example of maps. You can create the category of all sets and maps relations between sets.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You're saying the Category theory idea is more general. What is an example where the morphisms of catgeory theory are not relations between sets?

Comment: Does this help at all? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2488467/is-there-any-difference-of-relation-and-morphism

Comment: In the standard foundations, everything whatsoever is encoded as a set. So the line which we draw between sets and relations and "not" sets and relations is murky. The answer linked by Cybernetic is good because it provides you with a difference in the *use* and *conceptualisation* of some categories versus "categories of sets". But if you used the standard foundations everything would break down to sets. Points on a manifold, elements of a group, all are sets. Which kinda ruins the question. I recommend making the focus more precise

Answer (score 0):

Only certain relations will give a category. At a minimum to be a category you need identity morhisms and to make sure composition of morphisms are defined. This means that only relations that are reflexive and transitive will form a category.

Comment: Category theory has the same size problems that set theory has, but brushed under the table. Just like you can't have the set of all sets, you can't have a small category of all small categories. Just like in category theory you have a large categories, in set theory you have inaccessible, and you can consider all of the sets under certain inaccessible cardinal (read: all small sets), and just like category theory continue into higher up categories, in set theory you just have larger and larger inaccessibles.

Comment: Explicit construction can be found in "From Sets to Types to Categories to Sets" by Steve Awodey

Comment: My point was that categories can describe all sets, but sets cannot describe all categories.

Comment: And my point is that this is a misleading way to put it. The correct analogous to the category of sets, "Set", is "all sets bellow an inaccessible cardinal", and the analogous of "the set of all categories over an inaccessible cardinal" is the category of all small categories, Cat. 
Using the correct LCA, set theory can describe everything category theory can describe and more (e.g. in TG set theory), or even more (e.g. assuming proper class of wholeness cardinals). The advantage of category theory is not in it's expressability power

Comment: Furthermore, even the "standard" set theory (e.g. ZF, or the conservative extension NBG) can express pretty much the same stuff as category theory (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255425/what-is-the-use-of-grothendieck-universes-in-category-theory) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382270/reflection-principle-vs-universes))

Comment: Ah I don't think this is really helpful to answer the question here. I was trying to go for a simpler idea: That objects in a category need not be sets. That's all I was really going for. I suppose I can adjust my response to just say that.